# Why declaration of pointer points to unknown memory while definition is not?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I understand that following code returns segmentation fault because it tries to write to the part of memory where `q` points to (some random address) and this part of memory is not allowed to write by given process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char* p = "Hello";
  char* q;

  strcpy(q, p);
  printf("%s\n", q);
}
```

I also understand that it can be easily fixed by dynamically allocating appropriate amount of memory and pointing `q` to this memory, so `p` content can be safely copied to `q`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char* p = "Hello";
  char* q = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(q, p);
  printf("%s\n", q);
}
```

But why following example is working?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char* p = "Hello";
  printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

Isn't `char* p = "Hello";` also pointing to some unknown memory which is not allowed to write by given process?

Comment: @user3121023 oh that was scholar mistake thanks. I've deleted 2nd question not to be confused.

Comment: Person who down voted me please specify why, so I can improve the question. Thanks

Comment: Post is now more confusing as [@Xaver](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38485137/2410359) answered a part of the post deleted.  Suggest bringing it back for good etiquette.

Comment: None of the example attempt to modify what `p` points to.  So why ask "Isn't `char* p = "Hello";` also pointing to some unknown memory which is not allowed to write ..."

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
char* p = "Hello";
```

creates an array of six chars and sets them to `"Hello"` (the sixth char is the null-char). Then, it writes the memory address of this array to `p`. So `p` points to an initialized memory segment.

Concerning your second example: `p` contains the memory address of the char array `"Hello"`. If you want `q` to contain the same memory address, you have to use the command

```
q = p;
```

In the code

```
q = &p;
```

the types are incompatible, because `q` has type `char*`, whereas `&p` has type `char**`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `char* p = "Hello";`, the compiler will create a `char` array in a part of memory that is read-only at runtime, filled as `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`. The pointer `p` is filled with the address of this array. So the address is valid, it can be *read* from safely but not written to, it can be passed as a readable string to C's string functions, and you never need to worry about `malloc`ing and `free`ing string literals because they represent static arrays.

Comment: Why the down vote? Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

Comment: The type of string literals is not const.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `char *p = "Hello";`, the compiler internally creates a `const char[6]` to hold the string litteral, and then copy its address to `p`. Unfortunately, the type of a string litteral is not const, so you do not get any warning telling you that you are dropping a `const` attribute, but the string litteral shall not be modified.

So `p` point to a well defined memory zone and you can safely read from it for example with `printf("%s\n", p);`

The problem is that the string litteral shall not be modified, and trying to use the pointer for writing like in `p[1] = 'a';` invokes undefined behaviour. In common implementations, the compiler actually uses a read-only segment to store string litterals and you get a memory violation or segment violation error if you try to overwrite it.

But it is not *unknown* memory simply *read-only* one.

Comment: What is string litteral?